# Моб смотрит на игрока, но не идёт на него

Tags: unity3d

Мой моб при достижении определённой дистанции между игроком должен останавливаться (прямо перед ним) и начинать его бить. Проблема в том, что игрок может перемещаться и он может зайти к мобу сбоку, а моб на него повернуться уже не может. Необходимо как-то останавливать моба, но делать так, чтобы тот поворачивался к игроку. Вот код остановки, который есть сейчас:

```
else if(distanceFromPlayer < 15)
{
    nav.speed = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
else if(distanceFromPlayer < 15)
{
    nav.speed = 0;

    nav.updateRotation = false; // выключаем управление вращением агентом
    nav.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.transform.position - nav.transform.position); // или любой другой расчет ориентации
}
```

и не забудьте включить `nav.updateRotation = true` если игрок вышел из зоны, где моб останавливается.

Comment: Моб начинает пялить в одну точку и не двигается, пока distanceFromPlayer < 15

Comment: Обновил ответ, направление не то было. И тут направление будет работать, если у моба направление вперед соответствует оси Z. Если нет, то нужен другой расчет. Это просто пример.

Comment: теперь моб просто взлетает в воздух и смотрит где-то на 45 градусов вниз, однако смотрит на игрока

Comment: Сложно сказать, почему так происходит в вашем конкретном случае. На чем висит nav? Это nav mesh agent, насколько я понял. Он висит на мобе, или на каком-то перенте моба? Какие-то другие скрипты взаимодействуют с трансформом моба?

Comment: он висит на мобе, другие скрипты вроде не взаимодействуют